# how to connect HIVE server2 with kerberos authentication via PHP

Tags: php, hive, kerberos

I am new to PHP but in my application currently we are using PHP PDO connections to connect database sqlite3. Now we are moving to HIVE so please guide me steps to connect to HIVE using PHP. 
I connected to HIVE using java that is working but via PHP not much source is available in internet.

Please help